# Why my image couldn't show in Safari but can show in Chrome?

Tags: image, google-chrome, safari

The image url is [image url](http://images.news.quzhuan.me/news/pc_13/151120/pc_13_MTQ0Nzk4MTIwODMzNA_28044.jpeg),it can show in Chrome but can't show in Safari,why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension in the url of the image suggests that it is a jpeg image.
But the contents of the file are actually a webp image.
The contents of the file starts with the webp magic number: RIFFF\  WEBPVP8. 
Just open the file in a text editor to check yourself.

Webp is an image format currently only supported in Chrome and Opera browsers.
That would explain why the image will show in Chrome but not in safari, or IE or Firefox for that matter.

The easiest solution would be to convert the webp image to a JPEG image.