# img tag not loading dynamic image url in different browser except chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, microsoft-edge

I am trying to load images dynamically in my application.

```
<ion-card class="card-transition">
  <div class="card-block">
    <img #imageRef [src]="sanitizedUrl ? sanitizedUrl : defaultImagePath"
      (error)="handleImageError(imageRef, defaultImagePath)" alt="alt-image"
      class="card-contain-img" decoding="async" loading="lazy">
    <ion-radio *ngIf="showRadioButton" slot="start" [value]="item"></ion-radio>
  </div>
</ion-card>

this.sanitizedUrl = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.STYLE, this.item.Url);
```

the code is working fine with chrome browser, but when I use safari/edge browser it's not working.

I have done some research and found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817865/why-my-image-couldnt-show-in-safari-but-can-show-in-chrome?rq=3) which says safari does not support `.webp` format but did not find any proper solution yet.

https://dnaofsafetydev.sharepoint.com/sites/BluePrint/Shared%20Documents/Machine_Library/Machines/TTR-ERER33434_0201026433000096/Pictures/industrymachines.jpeg

This is the image url and it's loading properly on chrome. Is it because of I am trying to fetch image from sharepoint site?

Is there anything I need to add in `css` or the `img` tag which will help to resolve this image loading issue with different browsers?

Comment: _"This is the image url and it's loading properly on chrome."_ - but probably only because you already logged in to sharepoint in your browser - I am getting redirected to a login page first. _"but when I use safari/edge browser it's not working."_ - and when you open that image URL in those browsers directly - what happens ...?

Comment: I am experiencing the same as @CBroe (on IOS for Safari and Edge/Chrome on Windows10). Chrome 'remembers' that I have a Micrsoft-related login which points to the possibility your Chrome is logged in already.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that image url I shared is blocked for open use as per the company policy @CBroe

Comment: When i try to open image url directly in the edge/safari browser then I am able to see the image but not sure why its not loading in img tag @CBroe

Comment: _"When i try to open image url directly in the edge/safari browser then I am able to see the image"_ - so you must be logged in to Sharepoint in those browsers as well, I suppose. _"but not sure why its not loading in img tag"_ - perhaps those browsers are not sending any 3rd-party cookies with the request, so that Sharepoint doesn't _know_ that you are already logged-in, and therefor allowed to access the image.

Comment: No I am not logged in to sharepoint where i able to see the image directly in the browser. 
 is there anything which I need in response when i fetch image from the sharepoint?

Comment: Is there any error message in F12 console? I can't test with the image you provide as I don't have access to it. But I test with other SharePoint site image, and it can load properly in Edge if you have logged into that SharePoint site in Edge. I guess the issue still be related with the login/access states of that SharePoint site in browsers.